# Provocar error al deserializar json cuando una clase no contenga una propiedad del json C#

Tags: c#, class, jsonobject, deserialize

Al momento de deserializar un string en forma json a un objeto, algunas propiedades del json pueden ser no deserializadas al objeto, si la clase del objeto no contiene esa propiedad. Algo asi :

```
public Foo
{
  public string Propiedad1 {set; get;}
}

{
  "Propiedad1": "value1", 
  "Propiedad2": "value2"
}
```

Ahi la propiedad 2 del json se perderia pues la clase no contiene esa propiedad.
A lo que voy es que si existe alguna forma de provocar un error cuando esto pase. Es decir, que si la clase no tiene esa propiedad haya alguna forma de saberlo y validarlo

Comment: y eso depende como haces la deserealizacion....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para esto debes tener en cuenta el concepto de copia profunda (DeepCopy) pues muchas deserializaciones no son candidatas a realizar una Copia profunda.

por ejemplo:

Tu clase:

```
public class Foo2 
{
   public int Propiedad_2_1 {get; set;}
   public int Propiedad_2_2 {get; set;}
}

public class Foo
{
   public int Propiedad1 {get; set;}

   public int Propiedad2 {get; set;}

   //Esto no se puede deserializar.
   private Foo2 SubNodo2 {get ; set;};
}
```

La deserialización a menudo no va a ser posible para el miembro SubNodo2 por el grado de visibilidad.

Tu solución es deserializar en un diccionario y hacer la comparación de las Propiedades usando Reflection.

como se muestra a continuación:

Dada la clase:

```
public Foo
{
  public string Propiedad1 {set; get;}
}
```

y el JSON:

```
{
  "Propiedad1": "value1", 
  "Propiedad2": "value2"
}
```

Lo siguiente es una aproximación a tratar de deserializar respetando las propiedades de la clase Foo, debes tener claro el uso de genéricos:
(El código lo estoy arreglando, lo hice sin compilador, así que puede contener errores.)

```
public static bool TryDeserialize<T>(string json, T out objeto , out string eMessage ) where T : class , new()
{
  try 
  {
   //Debes usar UTF 8, por razones numéricas que no se debe discuir uso ut8json en vez de newtonsoft
   Dictionary<string,object> a = 
     JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string,object>>(json);
         objecto = new T();

    if (a!=null)
    {

         var properties = typeof(T);
         bool tieneTodasLasPropiedades = true;
         foreach( var prop in properties.GetProperties())
         {
            if ( !a.TryGetValue(prop.Name, out var valorEncontrado) )
            {
               tieneTodasLasPropiedades = tieneTodasLasPropiedades && false;
            } else
            {
                try
                {
                  //Lo correcto es validar que la propiedad sea escribible.
                  //Esto es un ejemplo, pero la idea buscar dentro de lo deserializado si existe cada propiedad.
                  prop.SetValue(objeto, (object)valorEncontrado , null);                      
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                   objeto = default;
                   return false;
                   //Como hacemos un TryDo Pattern no podemos lanzar excepciones para seguir el concepto.
                }
            }
         }
       
         if !(tieneTodasLasPropiedades)
         {
            objeto = default; // No puedes usar null directamente en versiones antiguas, pero en .NET 6 si soporta null en genéricos.
            return false;
         }



    }
    else
    {

    }
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
    return default;
  }
}
```

Así lo implementas:

```
if (TryDeserialize<Foo>("json", out Foo deserializado, out string eMessage ))
{
      deserializado.Propiedad1;
}
else
{
   // throws new Exception( eMessage );
}
```